# Emacs + Cider (Clojure) + Auto-Complete: How to get the docstring?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, clojure, cider

I am trying to properly configure emacs to write my Clojure code. I based my Emacs configurations on this [good blog post](http://blog.worldcognition.com/2012/07/setting-up-emacs-for-clojure-programming.html).

However, I did change a few settings like the theme he is using etc. I have been checking to get Auto-Complete (Eldoc? I am not sure) to display the docstring of the functions in Clojure, and from my own code.

I want to see the documentation like in that screenshot:

[image: eldoc]

However, I cannot get the "yellow" documentation box to appear. I am not sure if this is due to a misconfiguration in my `.emacs` file, or if it is a command I have to use or...

Here is my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/lib/noctilux-theme")

(require 'package):
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

;; Initialize all the ELPA packages (what is installed using the packages commands)    
(package-initialize)  

;; Set bigger fonts
(set-default-font "Courier New-13")  

;; Setup to have a french keyboard layout working   
(require 'iso-transl)  

;; Show parenthesis mode
(show-paren-mode 1)  

;; rainbow delimiters
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;; paredit
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(global-set-key [f7] 'paredit-mode)

;; theme
(load-theme 'noctilux t)

;; clojure-mode
(global-set-key [f9] 'cider-jack-in)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)

;; nrepl
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'nrepl-turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*nrepl*")
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)

;; Auto complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
;(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(setq ac-delay 0.0)
;(setq ac-use-quick-help t)
(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.0)
;(setq ac-use-fuzzy 1)
;(setq ac-auto-start 1)
;(setq ac-auto-show-menu 1)
(ac-config-default)

;; ac-nrepl
(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete" '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'nrepl-mode))


(defun set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function ()
  (setq completion-at-point-functions '(auto-complete)))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)

(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)


;; scroll one line at a time (less "jumpy" than defaults)

(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1))) ;; one line at a time

(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil) ;; don't accelerate scrolling

(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't) ;; scroll window under mouse

(setq scroll-step 1) ;; keyboard scroll one line at a time
```

### Update based on @syohex's comment bellow

Here is what I see in my CLJ buffers:

[image: CLJ buffer popup]

In the NREPL, I do see a "v" instead of a "d" (by the way, what does these letters means?). As I said in my comment, in NREPL, I do see the yellow box appearing, then when the popup appears, then the doc yellow box disapear. In the CLJ code buffers, the yellow box never open.

### Final Update

After some more testing, everything is working as expected. When the popup first shows, the yellow box disapear. However, when I start selecting different choices, then it reappears, at the right place.

Also, it started working in the CLJ buffers, and I see the letter "v" instead of "d" as seen in the sreenshot above. Maybe I forgot to start the NREPL, would have to re-test.

In any case, everything is working as expected.

Comment: rather late, but since I'm here and wondering the same thing: `by the way, what does these letters means?` Here as [defined](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/cider-interaction.el#L122)  in source code.

Comment: As a note to future travelers, CIDER now recommends using `company` for autocompletion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nrepl-mode-hook`, `nrepl-interaction-mode-hook`, `nrepl-mode` are obsoleted. You should use `cider-mode-hook`, `cider-repl-mode-hook`, `cider-mode` instead of them respectively.

And you should set `ac-quick-help-delay` to value more than `0`(for example `0.5`).
Patch is below.

```
--- nconf-orig.el   2014-05-21 16:51:40.056185465 +0900
+++ conf-new.el 2014-05-21 16:53:11.936182181 +0900
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@
 ;(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
 (setq ac-delay 0.0)
 ;(setq ac-use-quick-help t)
-(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.0)
+(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)
 ;(setq ac-use-fuzzy 1)
 ;(setq ac-auto-start 1)
 ;(setq ac-auto-show-menu 1)
@@ -51,9 +51,10 @@

 ;; ac-nrepl
 (require 'ac-nrepl)
-(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
-(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
-(eval-after-load "auto-complete" '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'nrepl-mode))
+(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
+(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
+(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
+(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode)


 (defun set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function ()
```

Comment: Thanks @syohex! This is a clear improvement, but still not 100% perfect. From the REPL, I now see the yellow box, but the behavior is: the yellow box appears first, then when the autocompletion popup appears, the yellow box with the docs disapear. I am not sure why. Also, I would like to have the same behavior when I am editing the CJL files in the other buffers (see the update of my post above)

Comment: After some more testing, everything is working as expected. When the popup first shows, the yellow box disappear. However, when I start selecting different choices, then it reappears, at the right place.

Also, it started working in the CLJ buffers, and I see the letter "v" instead of "d" as seen in the sreenshot above. Maybe I forgot to start the NREPL, would have to re-test.

In any case, everything is working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Actually this configuration and the former `ac-nrepl` is deprecated, refer to the new package [ac-cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/ac-cider#installation)

```
(require 'ac-cider)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-flyspell-workaround)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-cider-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-cider-setup)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
    '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

> the yellow box appears first, then when the autocompletion popup
>   appears, the yellow box with the docs disapear.

This behavior is caused by`(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)` since 0.5s is too fast

Change 0.5 to a bigger number (minimal value to work is 0.9 on my computer, but this may dependent on your computer's performance) or
delete `(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)` Since this would use the default: about 2.5s, it can resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am viewing this in 2020 and [ac-cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/ac-cider) is deprecated but you can use [company-mode](https://company-mode.github.io/) instead.

Use `M-x package-install company` to install and follow the [cider docs](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/usage/code_completion.html) to configure it for `cider-repl-mode` and `cider-mode`